# How to convert geospatial coordinates from top right, bottom left to top left and bottom right

Tags: gps, geospatial, couchbase

I am using a map that allows selecting a bounding box on a map and returns (lat, lon) for top right, and bottom left.

I am using couchbase geo spatial queries and they only support top_left bottom_right coordinates.

What's the formula to convert latitude and longitude values of two opposite corners from a rectangle from top_right bottom_left to top_left bottom_right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A self explanatory diagram

```
lat2 lon1 (top left)      -----   lat2 lon2 (top right)
         |                             |
         |                             |
lat1 lon1 (bottom left)   -----   lat1 lon2  (bottom right)
```

Input coordinates `(lat1, lon1)  (lat2, lon2)`

Output coordinates `(lat2, lon1) (lat1 lon2)`

As you can see there is no formula involved. All the necessary values are available. It's just a matter of correctly setting the coordinates variables.